# Appium JavaScript, how to write & execute my first test?

Tags: javascript, appium

I want to run tests with Appium written in JavaScript but I can't find any info on how to write/execute them. I have followed the tutorials that I have found and I am pretty sure that I have everything in place to get going.
I have installed:

```
npm install appium -g
npm install wd in my local directory
Android SDK 
my device's driver and I can see it listed when I run adb devices.
```

When I run `appium-doctor` everything is with green ticks, executing `appium &` starts the appium server (I think?) and everything looks fine. What do I need to do from here on?
What files I need to create?

Any info is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have everything setup that will allow you to run `mocha android-simple.js` from the [Appium node examples](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/tree/master/sample-code/examples/node).  You may need to `npm install` various modules required by the test's helpers before it will run.

If that works then the examples and [the javascript bindings docs](https://github.com/admc/wd) are a good starting point.